# Apply pd.Series by saving another column

Tags: python, pandas

My initial df is:

df =

```
    ID  location
0   141     [(45.1024, 7.7498), (45.1027, 7.75), (45.1072,...
1   403     [(45.0595, 7.6829), (45.0595, 7.6829), (45.056...
2   920     [(45.0695, 7.5454), (44.9727, 7.666), (44.9726..
```

after applying `b = df['location'].apply(pd.Series)` I get

```
1                   2                   3                    4
(45.1024, 7.7498)   (45.1027, 7.75)     (45.1072, 7.7568)   (45.1076, 7.7563)
...
```

I get partially what I want. But I'm loosing my column 'ID'. How I can save it and apply `pd.Series`?

Comment: include your desired output so we are clear on what you want

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas split column of lists into multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35491274/pandas-split-column-of-lists-into-multiple-columns)

Comment: Dont use `apply(pd.Series)`. It's really slow. Use; `df.iloc[:, :1].join(pd.DataFrame(df['location'].values.tolist()))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df = pd.concat([df, b], axis=1)
df = df.drop(labels=['location'], axis=1)
```